# Unwrapping Optional - Apple Watch Text Input

Tags: swift3, watchkit, option-type

I want to receive some text that has been inputted by the user on an Apple Watch. This is what I have so far:

```
presentTextInputController(withSuggestions: ["Michael","David","John","Lisa","Mary","Susan","Matthew","James","Jessica","Jennifer","Amanda","Emily","Dylan","Ross","Rupert"], allowedInputMode:   WKTextInputMode.plain) { (arr: [Any]?) in
        playerNames.playerOne = String(describing: arr)
        print(playerNames.playerOne)

    }
```

This always returns a optional like `Optional([Michael])`

I want it to return `Michael`

I have looked around about optionals but can't seem to find an anwser.

Comment: Do you want it to return `"Michael"` or `["Michael"]`?

Comment: Just "Michael". The first one please

Comment: How can I return arr as a string then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this code:

```
let suggestions = ["Michael", "David", "John", "Lisa", "Mary", "Susan", "Matthew", "James", "Jessica", "Jennifer", "Amanda", "Emily", "Dylan", "Ross", "Rupert"]

presentTextInputController(withSuggestions: suggestions, allowedInputMode: WKTextInputMode.plain) { (arr: [Any]?) in
    guard let arr = arr, let firstElement = arr.first as? String else { return }
    playerNames.playerOne = firstElement
    print(playerNames.playerOne)
}
```

Here are some documents you can refer to: [Optional Binding](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-ID333), [Guard Statement](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Statements.html#//apple_ref/swift/grammar/guard-statement).

Comment: It works really well but returns - [Michael]. How could I return just Michael?

Comment: I just edited my answer, but it will only work fine if `arr` always returns one element. I need you to provide more context of `arr`.

Comment: **Example**: `arr` = `["Michael"]`, It will work fine. But if `arr` = `["James", "Michael"]`, then it will return `"James"` because it will always take the first element.  I'm assuming that `arr` always has an element.

Comment: Yeah, you're welcome! If you need any help, leave a comment, I will come back.